# Getting smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError while sending email using python on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, cloud, smtplib, pythonanywhere

I created a python script that sends emails using python and deployed it on pythonanywhere.

Here's the code:

```
import smtplib
import csv
import time
from string import Template

email_address = 'youremail@gmail.com'
email_password = 'password'

def send_emails(email_address,email_password):
  while True:
    with open('quotesource.txt','r') as f:
        quotes = f.read()
        daily_quote_num= 0
        for quote in quotes.splitlines():
            view_quote = quote
            # opening user database
            with open('database.csv', 'r') as csv_database:
                database_reader = csv.reader(csv_database)
                # looping through user database

                for database_info in database_reader:
                    user_name = database_info[0]
                    user_email = database_info[1]
                    # sending email
                    t = Template('subject:Daily Quotes $num \n\n $quoteline\n \n Have a nice day $name !')
                    msg = t.substitute(num=daily_quote_num,quoteline= view_quote,name=user_name)
                    try:
                        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
                            smtp.ehlo()
                            smtp.starttls()
                            smtp.login(email_address, email_password)
                            smtp.sendmail(from_addr=email_address,to_addrs=user_email,msg=msg.encode('utf-8'))
                            smtp.quit()
                    except Exception as err:
                        raise(err)
                    daily_quote_num += 1
            time.sleep(86400)

print(send_emails(email_address,email_password))
```

But when I run my code(by the way I am using python 3) I get this error:

```
   raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
   smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv\n5.7.14 KAMZ41q6khk64CjUNQU3xj
   Bf4hohSdLujNyleDpsFQuzmwNAkIot0BkfdcE9DyK1gFpTh\n5.7.14       H-XuJMMPxDQnGiXrF0uRO4Z46iK1suCIM9hC5VUU5i5Rgdm09Wf6gnVloK_Rowff>\n5.7.14 Please log in via 
   your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g136sm23063683qke.82 - gsmtp')
```

**I have enabled less secure app feature and also IMAP on my gmail account and the code runs fine on my local computer but gets this error while running on python anywhere**

Comment: did you check links which you get in error ? Maybe there are useful information. And Google may block connections from some IPs for security reason - even if you use less secure app feature. Maybe generate special login/password for application.

Comment: I read them ,but the things that annoys me is that this code works fine on my pc but when I run it on pythonanywhere I get this error

Comment: some portals simply blocks access for security reason because spamers use these portals. So say "Thank you" to spammers and hackers.

Comment: BTW: did you check link in error message ? Maybe Google will ask you if this IP is safe and then all will work.

Comment: I checked all of them

Comment: Try using an app-specific password for your Gmail account.  See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers for more information.